# Clonezilla/Cloning::VERY basic Questions

Tags: clonezilla

I know that SE encourages single question questions. However mine seem so basic; and so related (and probably so easy to answer by an experienced cloner) that I'd like to try asking them all at once.
If I am askonce of the law, I will ask them separately.

- **Space requirements**: My C-drive reads "768 GB free of 930 GB"  (262 GB); my wife's: 1.54TB free of 1.8 TB (.26 TB = 260 GB) If I use
  Clonezilla to Clone (or Image) both drives, will the space used up by
  a Clonezilla clone/image be (approx) 522 GB?
- **Disk requirements**: (therefore)    Will a 1 TB hard disk handle the
     cloning/imaging of both of these    drives? (More specifically, can Clonezilla clone/image both drives on a single 1 TB drive?)
- **Compression** One wants a clone/image to be absolutely (presumably a disksum assures this) accurate and absolutely capable of being able
  to restore a computer. Does employing (Clonezilla) compression
  threaten reliability?
- **Clone vs Image**:For all practical purposes (clone
     diskA =>    tragedy => restore diskA), 
     is there a    difference between cloning and imaging?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for how to accept an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, approximately 522G, or even less; how much less depends on the data density.
2. Yes, a 1T HD will hold both images just fine.
3. No.
4. No, not for practical purposes.